# RxJava2 Detect zero event condition with Flowable

Tags: java, android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I am using an android library [FrangSierra](https://github.com/FrangSierra/RxFirebase) for listening to `Firebase` database events. This library returns `RxJava2` `Flowables` to work with. I show a loading dialog when I start loading data and need to hide it when data is received. Now the problem is when there is no data and I need to show an empty view because `Flowable` never calls `OnComplete`.

I tried applying `timeout` and the problem is it will probably always timeout after data is finished loading. I also want to keep subscription for future events. My question is how do I detect 0 records scenario here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `switchIfEmpty` operator:

```
Flowable.just(1)
        .filter(value -> (value != 1))
        .switchIfEmpty(Completable.fromRunnable(() -> System.out.println("Empty stream")).toFlowable())
        .subscribe();
```

Comment: How long will it wait? How will it know before data arrives? Checking docs now.